# PSExec and secure passwords

Tags: powershell, psexec

I am currently using PSexec with credentials which are stored in a CSV so i can iterate of each row. A basic example of this is.

```
$computerlist = Import-Csv C:\XXXXX\computerlist.csv

foreach( $user in $computerlist ) {

    $results = psexec ( "\\" + $user.ip ) -u ( $user.ip + "\" + $user.username ) -p $user.password query session

}
```

The passwords in the CSV are currently stored in plain text and could be viewed by anyone who gains access to the machine. Is there a better solution to dealing with these passwords?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think more carefully what's meant by "gains access to the machine". For stolen computer, consider using Bitlocker. For intrusive users, consider user rights and logon policies/permissions.

The most straight-forward way to secure the file is to use NTFS permissions. Store the file in directory and grant read access only for a specific group that contains script runner's accounts.

Encrypting the credential file is a chicken and egg -problem. You'd need to store the encryption key somewhere anyway, unless the key is prompted every time the script is being run. EFS can be used to some extent, but it isn't a silver bullet either.

Comment: Is it possible to store credentials in the windows credential store?

I guess my concern was the potential impact it could have storing all server passwords on one server. You raise a good point though.

Comment: @Billy92 You can do some trickery with `SecureString`s, as described in this two-part [blog article](http://www.adminarsenal.com/admin-arsenal-blog/secure-password-with-powershell-encrypting-credentials-part-1/). Still, the root problem with decrypting is that a key is needed.